# Google PubSub Pull Configuration Thresholds

Tags: google-cloud-platform

When you create a Topic, you can list it as pull or push. Once pull is chosen you client can send a series of [configuations](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/samples/pubsub-publisher-batch-settings) If we have a byte count threshold and a delay threshold. **If the delay threshould is reached before the bytecount threshold will the batch send?**

Default Settings:

> byteCountThreshold: 1000000

> elementCountThreshold:100

> delayThreshold: 10 milliseconds

Answer (score 1):

[C# API the one I am going to use](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/blob/master/apis/Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1/Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1/PublisherClient.cs#L583-L619) Per the api, if you have size configured then it will check the size first, if you do not meet the size thresholds it will go and check the time thresholds. So to answer the question

**If the size threshold is not meet but the time one is, then the time threshold would be used**